# What is the right answer of -1 % 4?

Tags: php, ruby, math

I'm using PHP for a project and I expect `-1 % 4` to return `3`. However, the final result is `-1` in PHP and I don't know why:

```
php > echo -1 % 4;
-1
```

I checked in Ruby IRB and the result is `3`:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts -1 % 4
3
```

Comment: % means `-1 mod(4)` and its equal to -1 in math

Comment: @safarov: Actually, `%` is usually defined as the **remainder** operator, which has a less well-defined mathematical definition.

Comment: @safarov "in math" is a broad statement. If you're dealing with Z_4, -1 and 3 are the same object.

Comment: FWIW, in Ruby `-1.remainder(4)` returns -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's defined in terms of division, such that:

```
a%b == a - (a/b)*b
```

For divisions with negative results, there are two possible definitions; either you round toward zero, or you round toward negative infinity.  Different programming languages have made that choice differently.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation for more information.

Comment: I'm proably reading this wrong, but wouldn't that calcuation give `a - a` thus creating 0?

Comment: @RobinCastlin: No, because this is being performed in integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

In these two specific languages, when handling integer divitions involving negative operands, PHP rounds the result toward zero, while Ruby rounds toward -infinity.

---

In PHP, from [Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> The result of the modulus operator `%` has the same sign as the dividend.

In Ruby, from [`Numeric#divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod):

> The quotient is rounded toward -infinity